# Is there any why to obtain email address from Outlook account without triggering security alert?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have an outlook add-in where I must get the current account email address in order for it to work properly. I used simple outlook application and filtered the existed emails to get the company email ID only

```
    public static string getOutlookEmail()
    {
        Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.Accounts accounts = myApp.Session.Accounts;
        int count = accounts.Count;
        string mailID = null;

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
           if (ifCompanyAccount(accounts[i].SmtpAddress.ToString();))
           {
               mailID = (accounts[i].SmtpAddress.ToString());
               i = count + 1;
               return mailID;
           }

           else 
           {
               return "No e-Mail";
           }
        }
     }
```

However, after installing the addIn and trigger the function the outlook will display the security alert message

[image]

I just want to get the email address, nothing more. Is there any other way to access the email address only without accessing the outlook information?

Answer (score 2):

If your code is running in Outlook addin, it will not be the subject to the security prompts as long as you use the `Outlook.Application` object passed to your addin instead of creating a new instance.

Do not use new `new Outlook.Application()` in a COM addin.

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (which never displays security prompt - I am its author) and its [RDOSession.Accounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) collection.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I actually cant use Redemption right now. But regarding passing the outlook object, I did this already and its working perfectly if am running my addin on new email instance like this (Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry), but my actual addin will be in the outer menu such as (FILE, HOME...etc) then my addin menu. I don't know exactly how can I use the current object to get the current account email address.

Comment: What do you mean by "outer menu"? Do you mean Explorer instead of Inspector? What difference does it make how your addin callback is invoked?

Comment: Yes, I mean Explorer. For example if I use Outlook.Explorer explorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer(). it will give an error on (this) not valid property. But on Inspector seems to work just fine. So if I am not able to use (this) how am I going to pass the current Outlook.Application?

Comment: I have not seen your code, so I do not really know what class "this" refers to in the two cases.

Comment: I found this line, Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer(). its working with me

Answer (score 0):

I think this did the trick for my issue, first I could not use (this) in the line `this.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntr`

But instead I used this way

```
Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.Accounts accounts = explorer.Session.Accounts;
```

To get the account info I basically didn't create new Outlook.Application as Dmitry suggested in the first place